# java.sql.SQLException in Glassfish server

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am trying to deploy sample Java EE Cargo Tracker application https://github.com/javaee/cargotracker

InteliiJ reports error:

```
C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.ejb-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\acc-config.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\admin-cli.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\admin-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\admin-util.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\amx-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\amx-javaee.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\annotation-framework.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ant.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\antlr-repackaged.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\aopalliance-repackaged.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\api-exporter.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\appclient-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\appclient-server-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\appclient.security.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\asm-all-repackaged.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\asm-all.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.configadmin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.eventadmin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.fileinstall.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.gogo.command.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\org.apache.felix.scr.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-cdi.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-ee-resources.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-ejb-container.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-http.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-javaee-base.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-jdbc.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-jpa.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-jta.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\autostart\osgi-web-container.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\backup.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\bean-validator-cdi.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\bean-validator.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cdi-api-fragment.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cdi-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\class-model.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cluster-admin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cluster-common.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cluster-ssh.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cmp-ejb-mapping.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cmp-enhancer.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cmp-generator-database.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cmp-internal-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cmp-model.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cmp-support-ejb.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cmp-support-sqlstore.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\cmp-utility.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\com.ibm.jbatch.container.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\com.ibm.jbatch.spi.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\common-util.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\concurrent-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\concurrent-impl.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\config-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\config-types.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\connectors-admin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\connectors-inbound-runtime.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\connectors-internal-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\connectors-runtime.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-cluster-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-common-full-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-common.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-community-branding-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-concurrent-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-corba-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-ejb-lite-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-ejb-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-jca-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-jdbc-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-jms-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-jts-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-plugin-service.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-updatecenter-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\console-web-plugin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\container-common.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\dataprovider.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\dbschema-repackaged.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\deployment-admin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\deployment-autodeploy.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\deployment-client.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\deployment-common.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\deployment-javaee-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\deployment-javaee-full.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\dol.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ejb-client.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ejb-container.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ejb-full-container.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ejb-internal-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ejb.security.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\endorsed\javax.annotation-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\endorsed\jaxb-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\endorsed\webservices-api-osgi.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\entitybean-container.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\flashlight-extra-jdk-packages.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\flashlight-framework.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-admingui-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-client-module.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-connectors-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-ejb-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-jms-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-jms-injection.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-jpa-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-load-balancer-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-restadmin-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-web-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gf-weld-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-batch-commands.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-batch-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-corba-csiv2-idl.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-corba-internal-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-corba-omgapi.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-corba-orb.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-ee-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-extra-jre-packages.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-grizzly-extra-all.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-mbeanserver.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-naming.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-oracle-jdbc-driver-packages.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish-registration.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\glassfish.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gmbal.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gms-adapter.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\gms-bootstrap.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\guava.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ha-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ha-file-store.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ha-shoal-cache-bootstrap.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ha-shoal-cache-store.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\hk2-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\hk2-config.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\hk2-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\hk2-locator.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\hk2-runlevel.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\hk2-utils.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\hk2.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\inmemory.jacc.provider.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\internal-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\j-interop-repackaged.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jackson-annotations.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jackson-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jackson-databind.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jackson-jaxrs-base.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jackson-jaxrs-json-provider.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jaspic.provider.framework.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javaee-kernel.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javamail-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javamail-runtime.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javassist.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.batch-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.el.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.enterprise.concurrent-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.enterprise.concurrent.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.enterprise.deploy-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.faces.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.inject.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.interceptor-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.jms-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.json.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.mail.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.management.j2ee-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.persistence.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.resource-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.security.auth.message-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.security.jacc-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.transaction-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.websocket-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.ws.rs-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.xml.registry-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\javax.xml.rpc-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jaxb-extra-osgi.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jaxb-osgi.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jboss-logging.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jdbc-admin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jdbc-config.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jdbc-runtime.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-bean-validation.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-cdi1x-servlet.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-cdi1x-transaction.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-cdi1x.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-client.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-common.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-container-grizzly2-http.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-container-servlet-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-container-servlet.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-entity-filtering.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-gf-ejb.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-guava.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-jaxb.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-json-jackson.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-json-jettison.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-json-processing.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-moxy.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-multipart.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-sse.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-mvc-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-mvc-jsp.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-mvc.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jersey-server.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jettison.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jms-admin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jms-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jmxremote_optional-repackaged.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jpa-container.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jsf-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jsftemplating.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jsonp-jaxrs.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jspcaching-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jsr109-impl.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jstl-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jta.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\jts.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\kernel.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\launcher.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ldapbp-repackaged.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\libpam4j-repackaged.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\load-balancer-admin.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\logging.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\management-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\metro-glue.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\mimepull.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\monitoring-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\nucleus-grizzly-all.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\nucleus-resources.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\orb-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\orb-enabler.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\orb-iiop.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\osgi-adapter.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\osgi-cli-remote.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\osgi-container.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\osgi-jpa-extension.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\osgi-resource-locator.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\persistence-common.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\pfl-asm.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\pfl-basic-tools.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\pfl-basic.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\pfl-dynamic.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\pfl-tf-tools.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\pfl-tf.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\pkg-client.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\registration-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\registration-impl.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\resources-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\resources-runtime.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\rest-client.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\rest-service.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\scattered-archive-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\schema2beans-repackaged.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\security-ee.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\security-services.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\security.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\shoal-cache.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\shoal-gms-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\shoal-gms-impl.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\simple-glassfish-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\soap-tcp.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\ssl-impl.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\stats77.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\stax2-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\transaction-internal-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\trilead-ssh2-repackaged.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-client.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-container-glassfish-cdi.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-container-glassfish-ejb.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-container-grizzly-client.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-container-servlet.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-server.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\tyrus-spi.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\war-util.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\web-cli.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\web-core.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\web-embed-api.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\web-glue.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\web-gui-plugin-common.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\web-ha.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\web-naming.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\web-sse.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\websecurity.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\webservices-connector.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\webservices-extra-jdk-packages.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\webservices-osgi.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\webservices.security.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\weld-integration-fragment.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\weld-integration.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\weld-osgi-bundle.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\woodstox-core-asl.jar;C:\glassfish\GF4\glassfish\modules\work-management.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3\plugins\JavaEE\lib\javaee-impl.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3\lib\platform-api.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3\plugins\Glassfish\lib\specifics\glassfish3.1-specifics.jar" com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 13568 com.intellij.javaee.oss.glassfish.agent.Glassfish31Agent
[2019-01-20 08:23:22,481] Artifact cargo-tracker:war: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
[2019-01-20 08:23:34,934] Artifact cargo-tracker:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Connected to server
[2019-01-20 08:23:41,515] Artifact cargo-tracker:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.


Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Part of log file from glassfish:

```
[2019-01-20T20:23:41.316+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1548008621316] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method]]

[2019-01-20T20:23:41.318+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1548008621318] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: The connection could not be allocated: Failed to start database '/tmp/cargo-tracker-database' with class loader java.net.URLClassLoader@1570103b, see the next exception for details.
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
```

...

I suppose problem is in database- `java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection.` But how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have specified any connection in connection pool in your domain.xml file?

Make sure you have defined something like this:

```
<jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource" res-type="javax.sql.XADataSource" name="__TimerPool">
  <property name="databaseName" value="/tmp/cargo-tracker-database"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

The error message is pretty clear - Glassfish can't connect to your database. Another thing you can also check is wether your database is running.